# C# Sign an exe programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, zip, self-extracting

I have an application that builds a self extracting zip file.  Is there a way to sign the self extracting zip file in code?

Comment: Erm some clues would be most helpful, e.g. what library are you using to build the zip?

Comment: Yes, there is a way

Comment: @PaulZahra, I'm using DotNetZip to generate the exe.  Does that matter?  I figure there would be some generic way of signing an exe.

Comment: @Jeeve Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.100).aspx